# No 'ASP.NET MVC 4' assemblies when installing Visual Studio Build Tools 2017

Tags: asp.net-mvc, installation, visual-studio-2017

I have a TeamCity build machine with VS2017 build tools installed. The problem is that I don't see any 'ASP.NET MVC 4' installed in "c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft ASP.NET" folder. The assemblies are required to build project that reference e.g. System.Web.Http namespace. When building, I am getting exactly such errors.

When running Visual Studio Build Tools 2017 on TeamCity build machine I have following Workloads installed:

- .NET desktop build tools
- Web development build tools
- Data storage and processing build tools

Individual components tab does not list ASP.NET MVC directly but I have "Advanced ASP.NET features installed.

Do I need to install any external component to enable building of ASP.NET MVC 4 on my build machine? Or maybe it is only including in 'Visual Studio Professional 2017' product, not the 'Visual Studio Build Tools 2017'?

Could it be the case that the installation is broken? 
(Microsoft ASP.NET folder contains "ASP.NET Web Stack 5" but as said earier the entire "ASP.NET MVC 4" is missing).

Thanks, Radek

Comment: You should probably reference the latest [ASP.NET MVC version 4 Nuget package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc/4.0.40804) in the relevant project and update the project to reference the nuget package assemblies

Comment: I don't have the nuget on my local dev machine and it builds fine with VS2017 Pro installed, so this is not it definitely.

Comment: That will be because you already have ASP.NET MVC 4 standalone already installed on your dev machine. Ideally you should uninstall it and use the nuget package as this will be more portable and your build service would be able to automatically install the nuget for the build. If you rely on installing the standalone on the build server, you'll probably run in to this issue again whenever you add a new build server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not familiar with Visual Studio Build Tools 2017. But you can try installing the standalone ASP.NET MVC 4 package:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/mvc4

Comment: Yes, it works for VS2017 as well, inspite it saying that it is meant for VS2010. Thanks a lot.

Comment: This works for vs2019 too.. Installing mvc4 through the visual studio installer didn't work for me but installing this standalone did. Wasted an hour or so on this.